# Android map zoom while keeping a center point

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to keep the center of the map fixed while zooming in/out? Right now when I try to zoom in/out the zoom is done where I start the gesture and I'd like to have it in the center so I'll be zooming over a location. Basically that's the same behaviour when you click on the zoom controls but using a pinch gesture.

Comment: Have you tried setting center after the zoom is changed? You can handle the zoom change event and call setCenter() every time zoom is changed.
Useful link: [events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events)

Comment: do you find the solution for your problem